# Firefox Group of Tabs: how to save and open as a group?

Tags: firefox

Firefox 69.0.1 on Ubuntu:  How does one save a group of tabs as single line-item?  It would be very useful to be able to recall the saved group in a future browsing session.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify they all open when you click on Home, or you can put them all in a folder on your Bookmark Bar, and when you want them all, right-click and choose Open All.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open all tabs (one by one) that you need to be able to close and open as a group.
2. Click on the first tab, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click on the last one to select all of them.
3. Right click on one and choose "Bookmark tabs"
4. Choose a folder name
5. Now you can go to Bookmarks, choose your folder name which expands on the right to show the bookmarked tabs. At the very bottom there is an option, "Open all in tabs".

You can now open and close all tabs as a group.